# Why should the infinite-dimensional representation of Poincare group induced by the unitary representation of little group be unitary?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, group-theory, representation-theory, unitarity, poincare-symmetry

In Weinberg's Quantum Field Theory (Vol. I, pages 64-67) it is stated that a unitary representation of little group induces a unitary representation of the Poincare group. But I don't understand how it works.

What is the way to show that the representation induced is unitary？ And is the unitarity dependent on the normalization factor N(p)？

---

Here I am to make my question more detailed.

On page 64, Weinberg defines $\Psi_{p,\sigma}=N(p)U(L(p))\Psi_{k,\sigma}$ where $k$ is the standard four-momentum.

Then on page 65, he states that $U(\Lambda)\Psi_{p,\sigma}=\left(\frac{N(p)}{N(\Lambda p)}\right)\sum\limits_{\sigma^\prime}D_{\sigma^\prime\sigma}(W(\Lambda,p))\Psi_{\Lambda p,\sigma^\prime}$ where $W$ is the so-called Wigner rotation.

My question is, if the representation of little group $D(W)$ is unitary, what's the way to show that $U(\Lambda)$ is unitary? Note that $U(\Lambda)$ now is represented by a "matrix" with continuous indices $p$ (of course, as well as discrete indices $\sigma$). If it's unitary, is the unitarity dependent on the normalization factor $N(p)$?

Comment: Please include the relevant paragraphs from Weinberg, using MathJax for equations. This will help clarify the context and notation used in the question.

Comment: @NiharKarve Thanks for your advice! I add some details.

Comment: [link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/779375/how-is-the-wigner-little-group-representation-of-poincar%c3%a9-group-unitary/779502#779502) you can check the answer to your question here. The bold part can resolve your problem if you are not into the details.